# Netty channel handlers pipeline for common HTTP communication?

Tags: netty

Is there a pipeline of Netty `ChannelHandlers` that would be a good base for common HTTP communication, and that does not have big impact on performances? Something like this:

- http decoder (`HttpRequestDecoder`)
- inflater (`HttpContentDecompressor`)
- http encoder (`HttpResponseEncoder`)
- chunk writer (`ChunkedWriteHandler`) - if this supports chunked transport
- deflater (`HttpContentCompressor`)
- aggregator (`HttpObjectAggregator`) - to work with full req/res objects
- something aware of `is100ContinueExpected`
- something aware of idle connections
- something aware of keep-alive
- something aware of file uploads

This is basically what most common HTTP servers should support and usually we plug our handler after above pipeline. Also, the order above is important, i.e. aggregator must come after encoder/decoder and so on. In other words, if user wants to build a proper server, he still has to *manually* write so many things. Not to mention various *options*, that are off by default, but *usually* make more sense to be set or enabled.

#### Questions

- Why we don't have anything like this?
- Is the list above complete?
- Does anyone have a working example of what I am looking for?
- Does such pipeline have any influence on performance?
- Is there some set of `option()` that is usually ok to be set?

All this on Netty 5. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to take a look into the existing generic HTTP servers written on top of Netty, such as [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress) and [Ratpack](http://www.ratpack.io/).

Comment: Doing that already - but it would be good if we have this on one place, officially supported, to save time for people.